# getting google oauth api access tokens

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have created a project and got a client id and a secret. But when practically utilizing them, how do I get the access token and refresh it periodically when its about to expire, programmatically using javascript.

Need to access the google drive api.

Comment: can you brief your question such as which google api you want to access  ?

Comment: drive api, added to the question

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask show us what you have tried by supplying a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.    Note I don't think you are going to get a refresh token with JavaScript.  Your going to have to request authentication again when it expires.   Use a server sided language if you want a off line access.

Comment: Im very new to using google drive apis. For youtube api, I just created an api key and used it in my xml http request and got the required data. But here I need to use the oauth 2.0 mechanism. So I have generated my client id and secret. Now how do I need to use these in a POST request with required parameters, for incase If i have to list the files in my google drive account. What should I do. Pls explain in detail.
Or how do I have to retrieve the access token and how to use it in the request.

It needs online access only. Not offline